# PHP media streamer

Tags: php, android, html, caching, video

The idea is that I want to create a simple PHP media streamer for my website.

I manage to stream a video on the web browser and in a `VideoView` on Android just fine.

**What I want to do**

- Stream this video to `multiple` users at once
- Cache the `HTML5` video on `sdcard` on android

**Problems**

- I can stream a video but for only `one` user
- I'm unable to get the video cached on the sdcard

**Codes**

**streamer.php**

```
<?php
$file = './'.$_GET["file"];
$pos = (isset($_GET["pos"])) ? intval($_GET["pos"]): 0;

header("Content-Type: video/x-flv");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

$fh = fopen($file,"rb");
fseek($fh, $pos);
fpassthru($fh);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

**page.html**

```
<HTML manifest="./cache.appcache">
  <video id="vid" controls>
  <source src="http://example.com/streamer.php?file=video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</HTML>
```

**cache.appcache**

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2014-03-08 v1.0.0
/video.mp4
```

**On android's side**

```
...
String appCachePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
wv.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
...
```

Comment: what error/issue are you getting on the PHP side - is it refusing to serve the second stream or failing in some way? Also what problem are you having writing the streamed file to the SD card on android?

Comment: I'm not receiving any error.. When I open the site on another PC the video wont load until the first one was done.

The problem in android is that when re-launching the app, the video is streamed all over again when it should just play directly @Offbeatmammal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, the caching issue is due to headers not send/set. Give this a try:

```
    header('Pragma: private');
    header('Expires: '.date('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 7200));
    header('Cache-control: private, max-age=7200, must-revalidate');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename='.md5($file));
```

Also: you set `header('Content-Type: video/x-flv');` but use `type="video/mp4"`. I guess, it should be `header('Content-Type: video/mp4');`

Next: for getting `$_GET["pos"]` to work, you need to calculate and set the `accept range` header accordingly.

Comment: That was awesome.. thanks a lot it worked like a charm, I can stream now the same video for multiple users in the same time..
I'll try to fix the caching on Android now and i'll give you my feedback @Jens-AndréKoch

Comment: Turns out it was a simple path problem.. When I was generating a dynamic manifest cache I figured it out.. I'll accept your answer since it solved one of my problems :) @Jens-AndréKoch